# How to trigger custom field reindex for catalog product rules on product save?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I have to display a text field dependent on the applied catalog product rule in the frontend, so I extended `Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule`, `Magento\CatalogRule\Api\Data\RuleInterface` and Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Indexer\ReindexRuleProduct to contain a custom text field.

The Catalog Product Rule with the text is applied for every product with special_price. After triggering reindexing of Catalog Rule Product index everything works fine and I can get the text from the rule. Now when I edit the Special_Price of another Product and save it, the rule isn't applied for this product and I have to trigger reindexing manually.

How can I trigger reindexing of catalog product rules with my custom field for this product on save automatically?